# Creating subplots in separate functions with matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, subplot

I am new to python and learning the ropes.  I am experimemnting using pyQT to build a GUI and want to be able to have a push button that displays a graph on an axes, and then another button that loads on image on another axes.  Im using subplot.  This is my attempt I've tried to pick up from searching, but it keeps opening a second figure and plotting to this.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import matplotlib.cm as cm

import random

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Open Image')
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.OpenImage)
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Exit")
        #self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.Quit)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItem("Item 1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Item 2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Item 3")
        self.txt1= QtGui.QTextEdit('Open Image')


        # set the layout
        #layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar,0,0,1,5)  #spans 1 row, 5 columns
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas,1,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.button,0,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2,0,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.quitButton,2,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.cancelButton,2,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox,3,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.txt1,2,3)
        layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def plot(self):
        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        # random data
        data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]

        # create some axes
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(231)
        ax1 = self.figure.add_subplot(232)



        # discards the old graph
        ax.hold(False)

        # plot data
        ax.plot(data, '*-')
        plt.grid(b=True, which='both', color='0.65',linestyle='-')

        # refresh canvas
        #self.canvas.draw()

        #Add 2nd Graph
        ax1 = self.figure.add_subplot(232)
        ax1.hold(False)

        # plot data
        data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]
        ax1.plot(data, 'r*-')
        plt.grid(b=True, which='both', color='0.65',linestyle='-')

        # refresh canvas
        self.canvas.draw()

    def OpenImage(self):

        #Create some axes
        ax2 = self.figure.add_subplot(233)
        ax3 = self.figure.add_subplot(234)
        ''' Load Image from File '''        
        #os.chdir('c:\')      
        M=plt.imread('c:\Image01.tif')
  #      ax2 = self.figure.add_subplot(233)
        ax2.hold(False)
        plt.imshow(M,cmap='gray')
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis


    def Quit(self):
       #return app.exec()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```